# Trying to reverse a string using a while loop & other specific conditions

Tags: python

So here is the deal, I need to reverse a user-defined string without using [::-1] or a reverse function call. I think I have a found a possible solution but I don't know enough about python to troubleshoot why it does not work, why can't I take the position of a string using an index?

```
name= str((input("Enter the name: ")))

i = len(name)

while i in range(len(name)) > 0:
    print(name[i], end = '')
    i = i - 1
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use str[::1] or str.reverse()?

Comment: _troubleshoot why it does not work_ If it's not working, you need to give us details.  Does this code produce an error?  Does it run but give incorrect results?  Saying "does not work" isn't helpful.

Comment: @JohnGordon I am not saying it doesn't work, I am saying 'why can't I take the position of a string using an index?'

Comment: @Ben just the rules I was given

Comment: _I am not saying it doesn't work_ You literally said "I don't know enough about python to troubleshoot why it does not work"...

Comment: Check out some of the answers given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we were to correct the solution you have provided, it would be this:

```
name= str((input("Enter the name: ")))
i = len(name) - 1

while i >= 0:
    print(name[i], end = '')
    i = i - 1
```

Comment: Why do you -1 from the i variable? Like why does that work but my code doesn't?

Comment: @Spencer Python strings start at index 0.  So "Steve" has length 5, but the valid indexes are 0 to 4.  That's why you subtract 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for i in range(len(name) - 1, -1, -1):
    print(name[i], end="")
```

Explaining the arguments in the `range()`, from left to right:

1. start: the value (index) `i` starts from
2. stop: the value where `i` stops exclusive by step
3. step: increment or decrement (-1 implies the decrement is by 1)

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it in the manner you are attempting is to use a **for loop** and count backwards through the string indices.

```
for i in range(1, len(name) + 1):
  print(name[-i])
```

This will iterate through a range of numbers (from 1 to n) and count backaward along your string by calling the negative indices of the string. `'helloworld'[-1] = d ...[-2] = l  ...[-3] = r` etc.

Answer (score -1):

The following code, will work, and will reverse a string.

```
        def reverseString(s: List[str]) -> str:
            left, right = 0, len(s) -1
            while left < right:
                s[left], s[right] = s[right], s[left]
                left += 1
                right -=1 
            return s
```

Answer (score -1):

the following code will work:

```
    a = input("enter your name: ")
    for b in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
          print(a[b], end = "")
```

Comment: Looks exactly like Geeky Quentin's answer